# lim cos(1/θ) = 0, when θ → 0. Why?

Tags: analysis, limits

Let $f(x)=x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ for $x\ne0$ and $f(0)=0$. =>

If we use Lagrange's theorem: $\exists \theta \in (0;x)$ and $f(x) - f(0) = f′(\theta)(x-0)$ =>

$$x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) - 0 = \left(2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{\theta}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{1}{\theta}\right)\right)(x - 0)$$ =>

Because $x>0$, we can divide both parts of equality on it =>

$$x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = 2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{\theta}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{1}{\theta}\right)$$

Also notice: if $x \to 0$, than obviously $\theta \to 0$ =>

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \lim_{x\to 0}2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{\theta}\right) - \cos\left(\frac{1}{\theta}\right)$$ =>

$$0 = 0 - \lim_{x\to 0}\cos\left(\frac{1}{\theta}\right)$$ =>

$$\lim_{\theta \to 0}\cos\left(\frac{1}{\theta}\right) = 0$$

Why?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(1/x)$ doesn't exist. You have supposed it to be zero.

Comment: Also, you may not selectively change some $\theta$s into $x$'s and then evaluate those to be $0$. If you want to adjust the variables, you'd have to do them all at once. Also btw: Has anybody ever mentioned that it's a little distracting to do $=>$ at the end of every line you write? :)

Comment: @Andy : Your MathJax coding style is atrocious.  I've cleaned it up.  Don't trust dumb web software packages.

Comment: @rschwieb, I think the appearance of $x$ in $2x\sin(1/\theta)$ etc. was probably just a typo.

Comment: @AntonioVargas I guess it's possible, but it also looks suspiciously like the person fell into the misconception that it was legal to switch some but not all variables. Apologies to the OP if it was merely a typo.

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks! It was my first post, sorry.

Comment: @Andy : Lots of people here have atrocious MathJax usage style, and it seems to be mainly the result of trusting software they find on the web.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is subtle, it is exactly the reason why the converse of L'Hospital rule doesn't work.

For each $x$ you get an $\theta_x$ with that property.

All you prove is that $0< \theta_x < x$ and

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\; \cos\left(\frac{1}{\theta_x}\right)=0.$$

And yes, $x \to 0$ implies that $\theta_x \to 0$, but $\theta_x$ is not a free variable converging to $0$. It is possible for example that all $\theta_x$ have the form $\frac{2}{(2n_x+1)\pi}$ where $n_x$ is an integer depending on $n$.

So the issue is that, even if $\theta_x \to 0$, you cannnot infer that

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\; \cos\left(\frac{1}{\theta_x}\right) = \lim_{\theta \to 0}\; \cos\left(\frac{1}{\theta}\right).$$

This equality is actually false.

Comment: I also think so. Thanks for reply!

Answer (score 2):

As $\theta$ approaches $0$ from the right, $\frac{1}{\theta}$ approaches infinity. It's easy to see that cosine does not have a limit as its input approaches infinity because the output reliably vibrates between $1$ and $-1$ forever. It does not settle down to any fixed value.

By the way, thanks for including your work. It shows us where numerous mistakes were made. Among these you dropped some terms, incorrectly evaluated a limit of $\sin(1/x)$ and fallaciously reasoned that you could change some but not all of the variables from terms of $\theta$ into terms of $x$ and remove some that way. Try not to repeat these mistakes!

Comment: Yes, you are right about limit of sin(1/x). But it was just a typo, sorry for that. Also I totally agree about $\theta$ . Thanks for your reply.